# Codesys add elements to a derived struct

Tags: struct, dynamic, codesys

Is it possible to add elements to an instance of struct.

```
TYPE StructBase:
STRUCT
   Start : INT;
   Complete : INT;
END_STRUCT
END_TYPE

StructDerived : StructBase;

StructDerived.StateInit : INT;
StructDerived.StateMoveFwd : INT;
```

The elements of StructDerived are going to be numbered in an 'enum' function. 
On completion the StructDerived elements are used for a case statement.

The idea is to have a complete abstract function ready with the basic functionalities i require. When this function is extended, it should be clear where what to add. so all units in the machine for example all have the same lay-out.

What i was looking into was something like this:

```
TYPE BaseState:
STRUCT
   EnumVal : INT;
   Name : STRING;
END_STRUCT
END_TYPE

TYPE StructBase:
STRUCT
   StateArray : ARRY [..] OF BaseState;
END_STRUCT
END_TYPE

StructDerived : StructBase;
StructDerived[0].Name := 'StateInit';
StructDerived[1].Name := 'StateMoveFwd';

So if i would use it in a case:
CASE AbortingState OF
    StructDerived[0].EnumVal:
        ....
```

The 'Name' is logged for state tracking. Looks like a lot of work where something like a *list* or *dictionary* would do the trick.

Thanks for any advice in this matter.

Answer (score 0):

First, you cannot use strings in `CASE`. Only `ANY_NUM` or `ANY_BYTE` general types. So, if you want to use enumeration, you will use it like this.

```
TYPE EN_STEPS: (
    enStateInit,
    enStateMoveFwd
);
END_TYPE

TYPE BaseState:
STRUCT
   EnumVal : INT;
   Step : EN_STEPS;
END_STRUCT
END_TYPE

GLOBAL_VAR
   StateArray : ARRAY [1..c_TOTAL] OF BaseState := 
       (EnumVal := 0, Step := enStateInit),
       (EnumVal := 0, Step := enStateMoveFwd);
END_VAR

GLOBAL_VAR CONSTANT
    c_TOTAL: INT := 2;
END_VAR
```

Then in program

```
VAR
    currentStep : EN_STEPS;
END_VAR

CASE currentStep OF
StateArray[0].Step:
    //do something
END_CASE
```

But this is not exactly clear why you are doing this. Looks like there is not a practical application for that. You could simply do

```
TYPE EN_STEPS: (
    enStateInit,
    enStateMoveFwd
);
END_TYPE

VAR
    currentStep : EN_STEPS;
END_VAR

CASE currentStep OF
enStateInit:
    //do something
END_CASE
```

The same thing.

Second, if you want to make a universal function that accepts a different number of elements you must use pointers. This is a general answer, if you edit your question and describe what you want to make in general, I will edit my answer and extend it with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Structured Text is a strongly typed language and it is not possible to dynamically add elements to a struct at runtime.

A data structure is not a function,therefor you should design a Function Block instead of a Struct if you intend to have a

> complete abstract function ready with the basic functionalities i
>   require

"*case of*" instructions have one *conditional variable* which is checked against one or many *conditional instructions* (integer literals).

**You can't use variables as your conditional instructions**.

You can use inheritance to extend Structs and Function Blocks in order to create a hierarchy of different modules and instatiate them in different occasions for different purposes.